# Thunderbird crash

Tags: thunderbird, crash, gmail

After manually updating Thunderbird to the latest version so that i can use GMAIL.
Thunderbird open and run nice until i restart my pc...
it doesn't reopen again so i try to start it via terminal and i got this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Y6cg.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zoDY.png

> GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
>   [calBackendLoader] Using libical backend at /home/superuser/.thunderbird/bi945wcp.default/extensions/{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}/components/libical-manifest
>   Bus error (core dumped)

I try to re-stall it/// it work but once i restart my computer it give the same error again